# setup ssl with nginx on linux

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm

I have this clients server where I would like to set up ssl on a site like this app..net

The server is running ubunto and written in laravel / php.

```
server {
    server_name <domain>.net www.<domain>.net;
    return 301 https://app.<domain>.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name app.<domain>.net;

    root /home/<domain>/www/site/public;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php? {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.<domain>.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/<domain>/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/<domain>/<domain>.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-R$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /home/<domain>/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/<domain>/logs/error.log;
}
```

This is my config file for my specifik site. Right now when I go to app..net I land on www..com, I have no idea what the problem is.

EDIT:

If i change the config file to the following:

```
server {
    server_name <domain>.net www.<domain>.net;
    return 301 http://<domain>.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name app.<domain>.net;

    root /home/<domain>/www/site/public;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php? {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.<domain>.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/<domain>/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/<domain>/<domain>.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-R$    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /home/<domain>/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/<domain>/logs/error.log;
}
```

Then I end up on the right page but no https

Comment: Do you have any other configs?

Comment: There is 5 config files in the sites-available folder

Comment: What about the sites-enabled folder?

Comment: There is 4 config files. But dont they just get copied from sites-available?

Comment: They aren't copied they should be sym-linked.... Can you post the config for the site that you end up on?

Comment: The site I end up on are not hosted on the same server

Comment: ok, in which case you need to find out where the redirect is happening. Can you curl the app site and add the response to the question

Comment: I have edited the question with a variasion of the config file that sents me to the right site

Comment: Have you set up DNS for the new domain, and can your server accept connections over port 443?

Comment: The domain is already setup and working over http, I would just like to have it working over https as well. I do not know, how can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, your domain does not have a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

This would explain that without listening on port 80 for that domain, NGINX would fall back to the default server which I assume to be your primary domain.

In any case, if you want automatic HTTPS on the app..net, you should add app..net to the first block that redirects HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This server block from your edited config:

```
server {
    server_name <domain>.net www.<domain>.net;
    return 301 http://<domain>.net$request_uri;
}
```

makes no sense and just creates endless redirect loop: from `http://<domain>.net/` back to `http://<domain>.net/`.

If main address is https://app..net/ and your want users to be redirected there (and always with https), just write:

```
server {
   server_name <domain>.net www.<domain>.net app.<domain>.net;
   return 301 https://app.<domain>.net/;
}

server {
   server_name app.<domain>.net;
   listen 443;
   ssl on;
   ...
}
```

If there is no other server { } blocks in nginx config first black can be written as

```
server {
   server_name _;
   listen 80 default_server;
   return 301 https://app.<domain>.net/;
}
```

Also check how PHP application is configured - may be some redirect sent by application.